# How to find points where $f(x,y)$ has a horizontal tangent line?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

It's a two variable function $f(x,y)$ with the level curve set to $0$, we are asked to find all points $(a,b)$ where it has a horizontal tangent line. How do I approach this? Since this is two variable I'm kinda confused.

Comment: Note that $\nabla f$ points perpendicular to level curves. So you can find wherever $\nabla f$ is vertical i.e. points on the level set where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is non-zero.

Comment: You can see that this is the same as the implicit differentiation method by noting that $\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{f_x}{f_y}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A two-variable function $f(x,y)$ with a level set $f(x,y)=0$ is just a curve in the $Oxy$ plane. You should:

- differentiate $f(x,y)=0$ with respect to $x$,
- assume $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ exist and do implicit differentiation whenever applicable,
- solve for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$,
- solve the equation $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$ for points with horizontal tangent line.

Comment: Thank you! So I took the equation with x and y mixed together, implicitly differentiate it with respect to x, isolate y' by itself and set it equal to 0. I go from there and got 1-x-2y=0, which is a line. Does that mean every point on that line forms a horizontal tangent line?

Comment: OH do I have to take this relation and plug it back in the original equation to solve for it?

Comment: @JaredLee It is possible you have to plug it back into the original equation to find all points $(a,b)$. If the answer has helped you don't forget to upvote it, and possibly accept it to show the question has been satisfactorily answered.